# Rails 4 - how to pass the value of "select_year()" from the view to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

rails noob here. I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for selecting "Years" in the view and pass this value to my controller so i can find the corresponding data from the database.

I'm not sure what the correct process is. so far i've made a dropdown menu in the view using "select_year()" and a link that basically directs back to the controller action "Index" and try to do an AJAX, and have the "index.js.erb" render the results onto the current view.

However, I'm not sure how to get the value from the selection i made with "select_year()", and should i pass this value to my **controller** to find the data or to the **model**?

Please feel free to point out any potential errors i have with the rest of the AJAX process, I haven't been able to test it because i cant even get the value from view to controller...

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @articles = Article.all

    @articleSelect = Article.find(???????????)

    # Would this be correct? @a = Article.find(params[:foo])


    respond_to do |format|

        format.js # render articles/index.js.erb
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="main">
        <!-- Year -->

        <%= select_year (Date.today, start_year: 1960, end_year: 2016, prompt: 'Choose a Year...') %>

<!-- I thought adding a field_name: "year" would help me to identify the value in the controller but it didn't work. -->

        <%= link_to "Show", articles_path, remote: true %>


        <div id="show">
            <%= render @dropDownResults %>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#show').append("<%= j render @dropDownResults %>");
```

**_dropDownResults.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <% @articleSelect.each do |a| %>
        <h1><%= a.title %></h1>
        <h2><%= a.author %></h2>
        <h3><%= a.year %></h3>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you mind adding the AJAX call to the view code? The answer would be changing something there.

Comment: oh i see, i thought by simply adding `remote: true` in the `link_to` and adding the `respond_to` in the controller is enough to make an AJAX call. so you are saying for every AJAX call i make i should add it directly in the view? right?

Comment: It would make your life a little easier, as you intend to use parameters, to have the AJAX call in a separated function as I described on the answer. You could have it in the `article.js` file instead of the view if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try submit your selected value with form using `remote:true`. Try change your code as below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="main">
        <%= form_tag(articles_path,:method=>'get', :remote => "true") do %>

        <%= select_year (Date.today, start_year: 1960, end_year: 2016, prompt: 'Choose a Year...') %>
        <%= submit_tag "Show" %>
        <% end %>


        <div id="show">
            <%= render @dropDownResults %>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In this way you can get your desired result. Or you can fire an ajax on dropdown change event and change code accordingly. With your current code you can't send selected option to index with link_to tag.

Comment: Hi thank you for your input! so using your method will i be able to do:

`@articleSelect = Article.find(params[:year])`?

Comment: Yes it will give you params[:year] in your controller action for selected value.

Comment: Hi, so i tried to access the params[:year] like above and it gave me this error, i don't think the selected value got passed for some reason:
`Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:6:in `index'`

Comment: It will not give you article id. try like Article.where(:year => params[:year]). Year should be a column in yuor article table. Try puts `params[:year]` in your controller and see if it get you to proper action also give you proper params vaalue

Comment: thank you, the previous error is gone now. However `form_tag` doesn't show up at all when i test it on the local rails server. it didn't generate the html tag for me.

Comment: It should be there otherwise you wont get params in your controller

Comment: fixed the last one, it turned out that i needed `<%= form_tag` not `<% form_tag`. however there's a new error, it seems that the `select_year` value has been picked up but wasn't able to transfer to the controller. Here's the error:

`Processing by ArticlesController#index as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "date"=>{"year"=>"2015"}, "commit"=>"Show"}
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."year" IS NULL`

in my controller i wrote:
`@articleSelect = Article.where(:year => params[:year])`
not sure why **:year** is still null

Comment: Its params[:date][:year] see your parms hash. This will give year value properly

Comment: @EdwardC If this answer your question properly then you can mark it as selected

Comment: ok so i did params[:date][:year] and it returned me a "NoMethodError in ArticlesController#index   undefined method []' for nil:NilClass" error. So i played around and wrote params[:date] and on the console it shows the database query as: `SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."year" = ?  [["year", "1960"]]` so i guess all i need now is a way to access the number not the array.

Comment: `Processing by ArticlesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "date"=>{"year"=>"1960"}, "commit"=>"Show"}
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."year" = ?  [["year", "1960"]]
  Rendered articles/_dropDownResults.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered articles/index.js.erb (4.0ms)`

Comment: nope, still NoMethodError in ArticlesController#index
undefined method []' for nil:NilClass error. I changed the way to do the select to :`<%= select('article', 'year', (1960..2016).map { |i| [i,i] } , include_blank: 'Select Year') %>`, this is what i got from the console: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "article"=>{"year"=>"1962"}, "commit"=>"Show"}` am i correct to assume the "1962" value is accessed with the "year" key and this hash is accessed with the "article" key? in the controller i have: `@articleSelect = Article.where(:year => params[:article][:year])`

Comment: lol i got it, turns out all i needed was `@articleSelect = Article.where(params[:article])`, that gave me the ["year", 2013] hash and i was able to query in the controller. Thank you so much for all your answers, you've been very patient! ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could add this function to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshDivShow (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "script",
        url: "<%= articles_path %>?authenticity_token=" + $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        data: {
            year: $('#yourYearInput').val()
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

and the value of the `year` parameter can be accessed from the controller function `index` as

```
params[:year]
```

or from the partials `index.js.erb` or `_dropDownResults.html.erb` with an injection

```
<%= params[:year] %>
```